# Mesh Generation for Computational Science in Python

Tags: python, math, computational-geometry, mesh

I have a need for a Python module/package that provides a mesh on which I can do computational science? I am not doing graphics, so I don't think the blender package is what I want.

Does anyone know of a good package?

Comment: A mesh for what? A planar region? A surface? A solid? What kind of computation do you intend to do on the mesh?

Comment: I just a 1+ D cartesian mesh; i.e., lots of boxes. I'm not sure what kind of calculations I'll be doing (yet). I'm just trying to get myself prepared when I will be doing calculations.

Answer (score 11):

The most useful packages out there are perhaps

- [mshr](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr),
- [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh),
- [dmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/dmsh),
- [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh), and
- [MeshPy](https://github.com/inducer/meshpy),
- [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo).

In addition, there is [optimesh](https://github.com/nschloe/optimesh) for improving the quality of any mesh.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of pygmsh, pygalmesh, dmsh, meshzoo, and optimesh.)

Comment: Are you aware of a package that can triangulate a circle using the number of points on the circumference? The 'dmsh' package triangulates a circle however it uses the length of each triangle edge along the circumference rather than the number of points

Comment: @mathsnerd What's wrong with adapting the edge length to the target number of points?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly then yes I am happy to do this as I really like the dmsh output for the circle but I am not sure how to because it's not like:
`circumference / h0 = numPoints` so I don't know how to adapt it. Do you have any advice?

Comment: @mathsnerd I don't understand what you mean. Of course it's `circumference / h0 = numPoints`, what else would it be? If you tried something and it didn't work, the stackoverflow comment section isn't the right place to discuss things.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to solve FE or CFD style equations on a mesh you can use [MeshPy](http://mathema.tician.de/software/meshpy)  in 2 and 3 dimensions. Meshpy is a nice wrapper around the existing tools [tetgen](http://tetgen.berlios.de/) and [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html).

If you're looking for more typical graphics style meshes, there was an interesting talk at PyCon 2011 ["Algorithmic Generation of OpenGL Geometry"](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/4299/pycon-2011-algorithmic-generat), which described  a pragmatic approach to procedural mesh generation. The code from the presentation is available [online](https://bitbucket.org/tartley/gloopy)

If you're interested in reconstruction of surfaces from data, you can't go past the [Standford 3D Scanning Repository](http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/), home of the Stanford Bunny

**Edit:**

A dependancy free alternative may be to use something like [gmsh](http://geuz.org/gmsh/), which is platform independent, and uses similar tools to meshpy in its back-end.

Comment: I had found the MeshPy package. If I understand correctly, it uses the Boost.Python package. I was hoping to avoid external dependencies; but with a complex package, I'm guessing it will be difficult to do without external dependencies.

Comment: On linux, the dependencies are pretty easy to satisfy. On windows, things could get a little more difficult because you'll also be dependent on the version of python. Installation of boost isn't so bad from source, just time consuming, the windows installer may get you going quicker if that helps http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: I am actually needing this on a Mac. Are the dependencies there bad?

Comment: MeshPy now comes with a subset of Boost.Python built in, so there are no external dependencies to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code adapted from Kardontchik's port,

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi as pi
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def ktrimesh(p,bars,pflag=0):
    # create the (x,y) data for the plot
    xx1 = p[bars[:,0],0]; yy1 = p[bars[:,0],1]
    xx2 = p[bars[:,1],0]; yy2 = p[bars[:,1],1]
    xmin = np.min(p[:,0])
    xmax = np.max(p[:,0])
    ymin = np.min(p[:,1])
    ymax = np.max(p[:,1])
    xmin = xmin - 0.05*(xmax - xmin)
    xmax = xmax + 0.05*(xmax - xmin)
    ymin = ymin - 0.05*(ymax - ymin)
    ymax = ymax + 0.05*(ymax - ymin)

    plt.figure()
    for i in range(len(xx1)):
        xp = np.array([xx1[i],xx2[i]])
        yp = np.array([yy1[i],yy2[i]])
        plt.plot(xmin,ymin,'.',xmax,ymax,'.',markersize=0.1)
        plt.plot(xp,yp,'k')
    plt.axis('equal')
    if pflag == 0:
        stitle = 'Triangular Mesh'
    if pflag == 1:
        stitle = 'Visual Boundary Integrity Check'
    #plt.title('Triangular Mesh')
    plt.title(stitle)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()
    return 1

def ccw_tri(p,t):
    """
    orients all the triangles counterclockwise
    """
    # vector A from vertex 0 to vertex 1
    # vector B from vertex 0 to vertex 2
    A01x = p[t[:,1],0] - p[t[:,0],0]
    A01y = p[t[:,1],1] - p[t[:,0],1]
    B02x = p[t[:,2],0] - p[t[:,0],0]
    B02y = p[t[:,2],1] - p[t[:,0],1]
    # if vertex 2 lies to the left of vector A the component z of
    # their vectorial product A^B is positive
    Cz = A01x*B02y - A01y*B02x
    a = t[np.where(Cz<0)]
    b = t[np.where(Cz>=0)]
    a[:,[1,2]] = a[:,[2,1]]
    t = np.concatenate((a, b))
    return t


def triqual_flag(p,t):
    # a(1,0), b(2,0), c(2,1)
    a = np.sqrt((p[t[:,1],0] - p[t[:,0],0])**2 + (p[t[:,1],1] - p[t[:,0],1])**2)
    b = np.sqrt((p[t[:,2],0] - p[t[:,0],0])**2 + (p[t[:,2],1] - p[t[:,0],1])**2)
    c = np.sqrt((p[t[:,2],0] - p[t[:,1],0])**2 + (p[t[:,2],1] - p[t[:,1],1])**2)
    A = 0.25*np.sqrt((a+b+c)*(b+c-a)*(a+c-b)*(a+b-c))
    R = 0.25*(a*b*c)/A
    r = 0.5*np.sqrt( (a+b-c)*(b+c-a)*(a+c-b)/(a+b+c) )
    q = 2.0*(r/R)
    min_edge = np.minimum(np.minimum(a,b),c)
    min_angle_deg = (180.0/np.pi)*np.arcsin(0.5*min_edge/R)
    
    min_q = np.min(q)
    min_ang = np.min(min_angle_deg)
    return min_q, min_ang

def triqual(p,t,fh,qlim=0.2):
    # a(1,0), b(2,0), c(2,1)
    a = np.sqrt((p[t[:,1],0] - p[t[:,0],0])**2 + (p[t[:,1],1] - p[t[:,0],1])**2)
    b = np.sqrt((p[t[:,2],0] - p[t[:,0],0])**2 + (p[t[:,2],1] - p[t[:,0],1])**2)
    c = np.sqrt((p[t[:,2],0] - p[t[:,1],0])**2 + (p[t[:,2],1] - p[t[:,1],1])**2)
    A = 0.25*np.sqrt((a+b+c)*(b+c-a)*(a+c-b)*(a+b-c))
    R = 0.25*(a*b*c)/A
    r = 0.5*np.sqrt( (a+b-c)*(b+c-a)*(a+c-b)/(a+b+c) )
    q = 2.0*(r/R)
    pmid = (p[t[:,0]] + p[t[:,1]] + p[t[:,2]])/3.0
    hmid = fh(pmid)
    Ah = A/hmid
    Anorm = Ah/np.mean(Ah)
    min_edge = np.minimum(np.minimum(a,b),c)
    min_angle_deg = (180.0/np.pi)*np.arcsin(0.5*min_edge/R)
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.hist(q)
    plt.title('Histogram;Triangle Statistics:q-factor,Minimum Angle and Area')
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.hist(min_angle_deg)
    plt.ylabel('Number of Triangles')
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.hist(Anorm)
    plt.xlabel('Note: for equilateral triangles q = 1 and angle = 60 deg')
    plt.show()

    indq = np.where(q < qlim)  # indq is a tuple: len(indq) = 1
    if list(indq[0]) != []:
        print ('List of triangles with q < %5.3f and the (x,y) location of their nodes' % qlim)
        print ('')
        print ('q     t[i]      t[nodes]         [x,y][0]       [x,y][1]       [x,y][2]')
        for i in indq[0]:
            print ('%.2f  %4d  [%4d,%4d,%4d]     [%+.2f,%+.2f]  [%+.2f,%+.2f]  [%+.2f,%+.2f]' % \
              (q[i],i,t[i,0],t[i,1],t[i,2],p[t[i,0],0],p[t[i,0],1],p[t[i,1],0],p[t[i,1],1],p[t[i,2],0],p[t[i,2],1]))
        print ('')
        # end of detailed data on worst offenders    
    return q,min_angle_deg,Anorm


class Circle:
    def __init__(self,xc,yc,r):
        self.xc, self.yc, self.r = xc, yc, r
    def __call__(self,p):
        xc, yc, r = self.xc, self.yc, self.r
        d = np.sqrt((p[:,0] - xc)**2 + (p[:,1] - yc)**2) - r
        return d

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,x1,x2,y1,y2):
        self.x1, self.x2, self.y1, self.y2 = x1,x2,y1,y2
    def __call__(self,p):
        x1,x2,y1,y2 = self.x1, self.x2, self.y1, self.y2
        d1 = p[:,1] - y1    # if p inside d1 > 0
        d2 = y2 - p[:,1]    # if p inside d2 > 0
        d3 = p[:,0] - x1    # if p inside d3 > 0
        d4 = x2 - p[:,0]    # if p inside d4 > 0
        d =  -np.minimum(np.minimum(np.minimum(d1,d2),d3),d4)
        return d

class Polygon:
    def __init__(self,verts):
        self.verts = verts
    def __call__(self,p):
        verts = self.verts
        # close the polygon
        cverts = np.zeros((len(verts)+1,2))
        cverts[0:-1] = verts
        cverts[-1] = verts[0]
        # initialize
        inside = np.zeros(len(p))
        dist = np.zeros(len(p))
        Cz = np.zeros(len(verts))  # z-components of the vectorial products
        dist_to_edge = np.zeros(len(verts))
        in_ref = np.ones(len(verts))
        # if np.sign(Cz) == in_ref then point is inside
        for j in range(len(p)):
            Cz = (cverts[1:,0] - cverts[0:-1,0])*(p[j,1] - cverts[0:-1,1]) - \
                 (cverts[1:,1] - cverts[0:-1,1])*(p[j,0] - cverts[0:-1,0])
            dist_to_edge = Cz/np.sqrt( \
                (cverts[1:,0] - cverts[0:-1,0])**2 + \
                (cverts[1:,1] - cverts[0:-1,1])**2)

            inside[j] = int(np.array_equal(np.sign(Cz),in_ref))
            dist[j] = (1 - 2*inside[j])*np.min(np.abs(dist_to_edge))
        return dist

class Union:
    def __init__(self,fd1,fd2):
        self.fd1, self.fd2 = fd1, fd2
    def __call__(self,p):
        fd1,fd2 = self.fd1, self.fd2
        d = np.minimum(fd1(p),fd2(p))
        return d

class Diff:
    def __init__(self,fd1,fd2):
        self.fd1, self.fd2 = fd1, fd2
    def __call__(self,p):
        fd1,fd2 = self.fd1, self.fd2
        d = np.maximum(fd1(p),-fd2(p))
        return d

class Intersect:
    def __init__(self,fd1,fd2):
        self.fd1, self.fd2 = fd1, fd2
    def __call__(self,p):
        fd1,fd2 = self.fd1, self.fd2
        d = np.maximum(fd1(p),fd2(p))
        return d

class Protate:
    def __init__(self,phi):
        self.phi = phi
    def __call__(self,p):
        phi = self.phi
        c = np.cos(phi)
        s = np.sin(phi)
        temp = np.copy(p[:,0])
        rp = np.copy(p)
        rp[:,0] = c*p[:,0] - s*p[:,1]
        rp[:,1] = s*temp + c*p[:,1]
        return rp

class Pshift:
    def __init__(self,x0,y0):
        self.x0, self.y0 = x0,y0
    def __call__(self,p):
        x0, y0 = self.x0, self.y0
        p[:,0] = p[:,0] + x0
        p[:,1] = p[:,1] + y0
        return p

def Ellipse_dist_to_minimize(t,p,xc,yc,a,b):
    x = xc + a*np.cos(t)    # coord x of the point on the ellipse
    y = yc + b*np.sin(t)    # coord y of the point on the ellipse
    dist = (p[0] - x)**2 + (p[1] - y)**2
    return dist

class Ellipse:
    def __init__(self,xc,yc,a,b):
        self.xc, self.yc, self.a, self.b = xc, yc, a, b
        self.t, self.verts = self.pick_points_on_shape()

    def pick_points_on_shape(self):
        xc, yc, a, b = self.xc, self.yc, self.a, self.b        
        c = np.array([xc,yc])
        t = np.linspace(0,(7.0/4.0)*pi,8)
        verts = np.zeros((8,2))
        verts[:,0] = c[0] + a*np.cos(t)
        verts[:,1] = c[1] + b*np.sin(t)
        return t, verts
        
    def inside_ellipse(self,p):
        xc, yc, a, b = self.xc, self.yc, self.a, self.b
        c = np.array([xc,yc])
        r, phase = self.rect_to_polar(p-c)
        r_ellipse = self.rellipse(phase)
        in_ref = np.ones(len(p))
        inside = 0.5 + 0.5*np.sign(r_ellipse-r)
        return inside

    def rect_to_polar(self,p):
        r = np.sqrt(p[:,0]**2 + p[:,1]**2)
        phase = np.arctan2(p[:,1],p[:,0])
        # note: np.arctan2(y,x) order; phase in +/- pi (+/- 180deg)
        return r, phase

    def rellipse(self,phi):
        a, b = self.a, self.b
        r = a*b/np.sqrt((b*np.cos(phi))**2 + (a*np.sin(phi))**2)
        return r

    def find_closest_vertex(self,point):
        t, verts = self.t, self.verts
        
        dist = np.zeros(len(t))
        for i in range(len(t)):
            dist[i] = (point[0] - verts[i,0])**2 + (point[1] - verts[i,1])**2
        ind = np.argmin(dist)
        t0 = t[ind]
        return t0   
    
    def __call__(self,p):
        xc, yc, a, b = self.xc, self.yc, self.a, self.b
        t, verts = self.t, self.verts
        dist = np.zeros(len(p))
        inside = self.inside_ellipse(p)
        for j in range(len(p)):
            t0 =  self.find_closest_vertex(p[j])  # initial guess to minimizer
            opt = fmin(Ellipse_dist_to_minimize,t0, \
                       args=(p[j],xc,yc,a,b),full_output=1,disp=0)
            # add full_output=1 so we can retrieve the min dist(squared)
            # (2nd argument of opt array, 1st argument is the optimum t)
            min_dist = np.sqrt(opt[1])
            dist[j] = min_dist*(1 - 2*inside[j])
        return dist

def distmesh(fd,fh,h0,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,pfix,ttol=0.1,dptol=0.001,Iflag=1,qmin=1.0):
    geps = 0.001*h0; deltat = 0.2; Fscale = 1.2
    deps = h0 * np.sqrt(np.spacing(1))

    random_seed = 17

    h0x = h0; h0y = h0*np.sqrt(3)/2  # to obtain equilateral triangles
    Nx = int(np.floor((xmax - xmin)/h0x))
    Ny = int(np.floor((ymax - ymin)/h0y))
    x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,Nx)
    y = np.linspace(ymin,ymax,Ny)
    # create the grid in the (x,y) plane
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    xx[1::2] = xx[1::2] + h0x/2.0   # shifts even rows by h0x/2
    p = np.zeros((np.size(xx),2))
    p[:,0] = np.reshape(xx,np.size(xx))
    p[:,1] = np.reshape(yy,np.size(yy))

    p = np.delete(p,np.where(fd(p) > geps),axis=0)

    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    r0 = 1.0/fh(p)**2
    p = np.concatenate((pfix,p[np.random.rand(len(p))<r0/max(r0),:]))

    pold = np.inf
    Num_of_Delaunay_triangulations = 0
    Num_of_Node_movements = 0  # dp = F*dt

    while (1):
        Num_of_Node_movements += 1
        if Iflag == 1 or Iflag == 3:  # Newton flag
            print ('Num_of_Node_movements = %3d' % (Num_of_Node_movements))
        if np.max(np.sqrt(np.sum((p - pold)**2,axis = 1))) > ttol:
            Num_of_Delaunay_triangulations += 1
            if Iflag == 1 or Iflag == 3:   # Delaunay flag
                print ('Num_of_Delaunay_triangulations = %3d' % \
                      (Num_of_Delaunay_triangulations))
            pold = p
            tri = Delaunay(p)  # instantiate a class
            t = tri.vertices
            pmid = (p[t[:,0]] + p[t[:,1]] + p[t[:,2]])/3.0
            t = t[np.where(fd(pmid) < -geps)]
            bars = np.concatenate((t[:,[0,1]],t[:,[0,2]], t[:,[1,2]]))
            bars = np.unique(np.sort(bars),axis=0)
            if Iflag == 4:
                min_q, min_angle_deg = triqual_flag(p,t)
                print ('Del iter: %3d, min q = %5.2f, min angle = %3.0f deg' \
                      % (Num_of_Delaunay_triangulations, min_q, min_angle_deg))
                if min_q > qmin:
                    break
            if Iflag == 2 or Iflag == 3:
                ktrimesh(p,bars)

        # move mesh points based on bar lengths L and forces F
        barvec = p[bars[:,0],:] - p[bars[:,1],:]
        L = np.sqrt(np.sum(barvec**2,axis=1))
        hbars = 0.5*(fh(p[bars[:,0],:]) + fh(p[bars[:,1],:]))
        L0 = hbars*Fscale*np.sqrt(np.sum(L**2)/np.sum(hbars**2))
        F = np.maximum(L0-L,0)
        Fvec = np.column_stack((F,F))*(barvec/np.column_stack((L,L)))
        Ftot = np.zeros((len(p),2))
        n = len(bars)
        for j in range(n):
            Ftot[bars[j,0],:] += Fvec[j,:]  # the : for the (x,y) components

            Ftot[bars[j,1],:] -= Fvec[j,:]
            
        # force = 0 at fixed points, so they do not move:
        Ftot[0: len(pfix),:] = 0

        # update the node positions
        p = p + deltat*Ftot

        # bring outside points back to the boundary
        d = fd(p); ix = d > 0   # find points outside (d > 0)
        dpx = np.column_stack((p[ix,0] + deps,p[ix,1]))
        dgradx = (fd(dpx) - d[ix])/deps
        dpy = np.column_stack((p[ix,0], p[ix,1] + deps))
        dgrady = (fd(dpy) - d[ix])/deps
        p[ix,:] = p[ix,:] - np.column_stack((dgradx*d[ix], dgrady*d[ix]))

        # termination criterium: all interior nodes move less than dptol:

        if max(np.sqrt(np.sum(deltat*Ftot[d<-geps,:]**2,axis=1))/h0) < dptol:
            break

    final_tri = Delaunay(p)  # another instantiation of the class
    t = final_tri.vertices
    pmid = (p[t[:,0]] + p[t[:,1]] + p[t[:,2]])/3.0
    # keep the triangles whose geometrical center is inside the shape
    t = t[np.where(fd(pmid) < -geps)]
    bars = np.concatenate((t[:,[0,1]],t[:,[0,2]], t[:,[1,2]]))
    # delete repeated bars
    #bars = unique_rows(np.sort(bars))
    bars = np.unique(np.sort(bars),axis=0)
    # orient all the triangles counterclockwise (ccw)
    t = ccw_tri(p,t)
    # graphical output of the current mesh
    ktrimesh(p,bars)
    triqual(p,t,fh)
    return p,t,bars

def boundary_bars(t):
    # create the bars (edges) of every triangle
    bars = np.concatenate((t[:,[0,1]],t[:,[0,2]], t[:,[1,2]]))
    # sort all the bars
    data = np.sort(bars)
    # find the bars that are not repeated
    Delaunay_bars = dict()
    for row in data:
        row = tuple(row)
        if row in Delaunay_bars:
            Delaunay_bars[row] += 1
        else:
            Delaunay_bars[row] = 1
    # return the keys of Delaunay_bars whose value is 1 (non-repeated bars)
    bbars = []
    for key in Delaunay_bars:
        if Delaunay_bars[key] == 1:
            bbars.append(key)
    bbars = np.asarray(bbars)
    return bbars   

def plot_shapes(xc,yc,r):
    # circle for plotting
    t_cir = np.linspace(0,2*pi)
    x_cir = xc + r*np.cos(t_cir)
    y_cir = yc + r*np.sin(t_cir)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x_cir,y_cir)
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('Shapes')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.axis('equal')
    #plt.show()
    return

plt.close('all')

xc = 0; yc = 0; r = 1.0

x1,y1 = -1.0,-2.0
x2,y2 = 2.0,3.0

plot_shapes(xc,yc,r)

xmin = -1.5; ymin = -1.5
xmax = 1.5; ymax = 1.5
h0 = 0.4 

pfix = np.zeros((0,2))   # null 2D array, no fixed points provided

fd = Circle(xc,yc,r)

fh = lambda p: np.ones(len(p))

p,t,bars = distmesh(fd,fh,h0,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,pfix,Iflag=4)
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using NumPy (especially if you've used MATLAB before). Many computational scientists / mechanical engineers working in python might agree, but I'm biased as it found it's way into much of the last year of my research. It's part of SciPy:  [Link](https://numpy.org/)
I was fond of *numpy.linspace(a,b,N)* which makes an N length vector of equally spaced values from a to b. You can use *numpy.ndarray* to make a N x M matrix, or if you want 2D arrays use *numpy.meshgrid*.

Comment: the mesh you talked about here is NOT the mesh others care about....