# How to generate approximately equally spaced points in an area?

Tags: python, opencv, shapely

Well I am finding a way to generate points equally distanced from each other in an area (or a polygon)

I find a very useful source of doing it

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141184/how-to-generate-approximately-equally-spaced-points-efficiently

https://newbedev.com/how-to-generate-approximately-equally-spaced-points-efficiently

However, I do not code C, I literally can not understand (or convert it to python code).

I am definitely not a math guy, just a problem while coding that I need to find a solution.

If you can find any sources or have codes that can perform it please share it to me.

Comment: This is not C language, it's Mathematica language

Comment: Check out this answer, however you would have to experiment with it a little: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797164/12118546